# Username's regular expression in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito for authenticating my application.As per the AWS Cognito guidelines, a proper username should follow the regular expression as follows
**[\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}]+**
What does this regular expression mean?

Comment: i upvoted because the specificity of this question is actually useful. AWS Cognito HATES spaces and will throw this error if you submit a username with a trailing space. I suspect that was the problem OP was facing. So for the sake of posterity, to dismiss this error you might need to `trim()` your username payload before dispatching to AWS

Comment: Oh, where did you find those guidelines? Share the link please.

Answer (score 15):

This expression allows almost any kind of character and must have at least 1 character to be inputted.

If you put this regular expression through [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), it will tell you what each expression is used for.

So for your one:

> \p{L} matches any kind of letter from any language.
>
> \p{M} matches a character intended to be combined with another
> character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.)
>
> \p{S} matches any math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing
> characters, etc.
>
> \p{N} matches any kind of numeric character in any script.
>
> \p{P} matches any kind of punctuation character.
>
> '+' Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

Comment: in other words, it can contain pretty much everything except white space characters

Comment: Could you point me to exact point in documentation this is specified?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolidentityprovider.html in ProviderName, you can see the pattern that the String should match, it is a string with no spaces

Comment: I'm not sure what the regex was when @stamstam left their comment, but currently the regex doesn't allow to start or end with an underline, and the afore mentioned "almost anything", but as the 2nd character: `[^_][\p{L}\p{M}\p{S}\p{N}\p{P}][^_]+`  -- I almost suspect this is wrong?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I think you're onto something! 